# Can I ask a same question after several years?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask the same question asking a recommendation for software after several years of the original question?

After 5 or more years, new software may have appeared.

Answer (score 5):

Practically I feel like a bounty is the way to go here

Alternatively, very carefully, asking a more specific question asking for support of current hardware platforms might work - *referring* back to the other question and explaining why the existing software options may fall short